# Can I store int and enum together?

Tags: c#

Example, I have a random number, but it can have "special numbers" values. Something like that:

```
enum XNumber { INFINITY, NEGATIVE, int }
```

So I could store:

```
var i = XNumber.INFINITY;
var i = XNumber.NEGATIVE;
var i = (XNumber) 1;
var i = (XNumber) 500;
var i = (XNumber) -1000;
```

If not, what are my possibilities to do that?

Comment: did you mean `var i = (XNumber) -1000;` should result in `XNumber.NEGATIVE`?

Comment: If @JenishRabadiya is correct, then my answer (while not incorrect) will need modification.

Answer (score 2):

An `enum` can be cast to/from an `int` <strike>provided the values match up</strike>. Note that you can assign numeric values to enum values. For instance,

```
namespace Test
{
    enum SpecialValue
    {
        Zero = 0,
        Five = 5,
        Seventy = 70
    }

    private void method()
    {
        var five = (SpecialValue)5; // == SpecialValue.Five
        int seventy = (int)SpecialValue.Seventy; // == 70
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that the values do not have to match up: An enum type can have any value of its underlying type; it's not restricted to its members. *SpecialValue anyValue = (SpecialValue)42;* is perfectly valid, and the value of anyValue will be 42.

Comment: @WillemvanRumpt: You're right - I've edited my answer according. Many thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is probably putting both the `int` and the `enum` into a `struct`. You can define conversion operators and arithmetic operators to make working with your type easier.

e.g.

```
struct XNumber {
  private enum SpecialValue { Normal, Negative, Infinity}
  private int value;
  private SpecialValue kind;

  public XNumber Infinity = new XNumber { kind = SpecialValue.Infinity };
  public XNumber Negative = new XNumber { kind = SpecialValue.Negative };

  public static implicit operator XNumber(int value) {
    if (value < 0)
      return new XNumber { kind = SpecialValue.Negative };
    return new XNumber { value = value };
  }

  // ...
}
```

Something like that, depending on your exact needs.

Another way, if you don't need the full range of `int`, is to use special values for infinity and negative and you only need to store the `int`. Still a `struct`, you should still define conversions and operators so that everything matches up. While you can get away with just an `enum`, as Wai Ha Lee notes, I'd not recommend it, as you essentially have an own type that has its own semantics (just that those happen to be somewhat supported by `enum`s in C#).